# How to count number of duplicated items in my from relational table

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct, having-clause

I have `order` and a `product` tables. The order table looks like this:

```
uid  id  ref     order_id
---  --  ------  --------------
1    3   abc.    112
2    3   def     124
```

And the product table looke liks this

```
uid  id  sku     order_id
---  --  ------  --------------
1    6   rs-123  112
2    7   rs-123  112
2    8   rs-abc  124
```

So I need a query where I get all the orders that have more than one identical sku like so:

```
order_id        sku          qty
--------        ---------    --------
112             rs-123       2
```

There could be orders with 2, 3 or more items with same sku. I do not want show any order that does not have duplicated skus

I've tried this:

```
SELECT sku, order_id,
COUNT(distinct sku) As Total
FROM products
GROUP BY order_id
HAVING (COUNT(distinct sku) > 1)
```

But it's not giving the expected results. Any ideas?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Just add `sku` to the `GROUP BY` clause, and remove `distinct` from the counts - you might as well use `COUNT(*)`:

```
SELECT sku, order_id, COUNT(*) As Total
FROM products
GROUP BY sku, order_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```